# How to make an equilateral triangle using GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot my data into two-dimensional barycentric equilateral triangle using GNUplot.

I'm using the following commands:

```
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
set arrow 1 from 0,0 to .5,sqrt(3)/2 nohead front lt -1 lw 1
set arrow 2 from 0,0 to 1,0          nohead front lt -1 lw 1
set arrow 3 from 1,0 to .5,sqrt(3)/2 nohead front lt -1 lw 1
set label 1 "1" at 0.5,sqrt(3)/2+.05
set label 2 "2" at 1+.05,0
set label 3 "3" at -.05,0
plot 'data.file'
```

The above mentioned commands does not create an equilateral triangle instead its making Isosceles triangle.

Please help me!

With Regards,
Swati

Comment: What does `sqrt(3)` return?  Does `sqrt(3.0)` return something else?

Comment: sqrt(3.0) is giving the same return what sqrt(3) is giving.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that its a barycentric equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that your figure is being produced with uneven X/Y scaling, with the internal coordinates of your triangle being correct, but the output, being isosceles.

Try adding a command

```
set size square
```

For more information check [this FAQ](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot1-e.html#5.4).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem. I created a file called triangle.dat. It contains 1 line indicating where to draw the triangle.

```
1.0 1.0
```

Then in my "myplot.gnu"

```
set pointsize 1.5
plot "triangle.dat" pt 9 linecolor rgb "black"
```

This will plot a black equilateral triangle at point 1.0, 1.0. Change pointsize to change the size.

If you have already plotted some other points, then use replot instead of plot.